# parsing the xml to get the root element and then add a tag dynamically under the root tag

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I want to parse the xml file to get the root element. Then append add the tag named *first-name* under that root tag. How do I do this ? This is what I have been doing right now :

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();            
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        Element blobKey_E = document.createElement("first-name");
        blobKey_E.appendChild( document.createTextNode( name ) );
        // NOW APPEND blobKey_E to the root element 
        // After getting the root element from the xml in some directory

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Personal Site_Testers/web/xml/xml_1.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
root.appendChild(document.createElement("first-name"));
```

Will append `first-name` to the end of the DOM tree

Inserting into the first position is a little more difficult...

```
Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
if (root.hasChildNodes()) {
    Node firstChild = root.getFirstChild();
    root.insertBefore(document.createElement("first-name"), firstChild);
} else {
    // Append to as per previous example
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
Eleement firstName = document.createElement("first-name");
firstName.setTextContent("Henry");
```

Comment: `root.appendChild(document.createElement("first-name"));` this is fine . how to insert text inside the tag `first-name` ?